# Laravel Eloquent: how can I get third table relation using Pivot

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot

I can't solve this with Eloquent correctly.

Assuming I have this tables:

```
--- Users ---
id (primary)

--- Clients ---

dni (primary)

--- Notifications ---
notification_id (primary)
client_dni (foreign key of Clients table)

--- Clients_Users --- (Pivot table)
client_dni
user_id
```

Explanation: A user have multiple clients, and each clients have notifications.

I have to get all the notifications corresponding to a single User. This means, all the notifications with a single function of all the clients that have a user. Something like User::notifications.

The problem is that I can't access directly to notifications for User, because Notifications is linked with Clients.

I appreciate your help... Two hours and I can't solve this. I tried with hasManyThrough but I think that is not for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I think that this is not recommended and Eloquent must have a better way... but:

```
        $notificaciones = Notifications::
        join('clients', 'notifications.client_dni', '=', 'clients.dni')
        ->join('clients_users', 'clients_users.client_dni', '=', 'clients.dni')
        ->select(['clients.dni as client.dni',
            'clients.name as client.name',
            'clients.surname as client.surname',
            'clients.empresa',
            'notifications.notification_id',
            'notifications.subject',
            'notifications.isRead',
            'notifications.date',
            'clients.procedencia'])
        ->where("clients_users.user_id", "=", "".Auth::user()->id."");

    return (datatables($notificaciones)->toJson());
```

In my get Notifications query I join the pivot table and check if the user ID match with theclient id... It would be better with simply $user->notifications , but for the moment I will go with this.

I will wait in case someone has a better solution!